# Continuous Delivery for FUSE OSS and Github

Tags: github, fuse, continuous-delivery

I would like to set up a continuous delivery cycle for my open source application. It is based on Linux's Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE). I tried to set it up on [CloudBees' Jenkins](http://www.cloudbees.com/), which provided decent free accounts, but I did not have root access, which is problematic as my project has many dependencies. I went on to use [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org), which works great for testing internal APIs, since I have root access to install dependencies. But it does [not support FUSE](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1100), so I cannot run tests on the filesystem directly.
According to my experience with Travis CI, a Continuous Delivery approach would likely prevent many bugs from being released and could help to identify problems more quickly.

Is there a service similar to Travis CI, which integrates with Github, allows root access, and supports FUSE?

[EDIT]
Vi. suggests to run User Mode Linux on a Travis-ci machine, to emulate FUSE. To summarize the progress achieved with Vi.s help:

1. For setting up UML with more memory, network access and access to the file system execute:

   ```
   /usr/bin/linux.uml init=script_to_run.sh rootfstype=hostfs rw eth0=slirp mem=2G
   ```

Inside the user script, call:

```
# Enable fuse module.
insmod /usr/lib/uml/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko

# Set up TCP/UDP network access.
ifconfig lo up
ifconfig eth0 10.0.2.15
ip route add default via 10.0.2.1
```

2. If you work with gcc, set your PATH variable:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
   ```
3. If you need procfs, execute this inside UML:

   ```
   mount none /proc -t hppfs
   ```
4. For Python, you should activate the virtual environment inside UML:

   ```
   source /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.6.9/bin/activate
   ```

The path to `activate` can be found by issuing the following command before starting UML:

```
echo "Path to Python executable: "$(which python)
```

Still I cannot run FUSE:

In short:

```
`fuse' likely not compiled with -mcmodel=kernel
insmod: error inserting '/usr/lib/uml/modules/3.2.2/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko': -1 Invalid module format
modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.2.2/modules.dep: No such file or directory
modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.2.2/modules.dep: No such file or directory
[...]
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

Comment: Maybe UML (User mode linux) can be used as a workaround?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this is similar to a virtual machine. I would have to check how much resources it takes to set it up for each and every test, too see if this solution is feasible. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Travis-CI allows installing system packages, including UML (User Mode Linux).

You can start your application inside UML (with a helper script). Example: https://travis-ci.org/vi/execfuse/builds/47789978

Here is the helper script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURDIR="`pwd`"

cat > umltest.inner.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
(
   export PATH="$PATH"
   set -e
   set -x
   insmod /usr/lib/uml/modules/\`uname -r\`/kernel/fs/fuse/fuse.ko
   cd "$CURDIR"
   ./tests.sh
   echo Success
)
echo "\$?" > "$CURDIR"/umltest.status
halt -f
EOF

chmod +x umltest.inner.sh

/usr/bin/linux.uml init=`pwd`/umltest.inner.sh rootfstype=hostfs rw

exit $(<umltest.status)
```

Supplementary commands in `.travis.yml`:

```
- sudo apt-get install -qq libfuse-dev pkg-config fuse user-mode-linux
- sudo mknod /dev/fuse c 10 229
- sudo chmod 666 /dev/fuse
```

Comment: I tried to use your setup, but I cannot get network access which is required for my tests. I added the argument 'eth0=tuntap,,,$myip', but ifconfig -a does not show any device.

Comment: @phobic, I can create a networking-enabled version of the script. Easiest mode: `eth0=slirp` to `linux.uml` command line, then `ifconfig lo up; ifconfig eth0 10.0.2.15; ip route add default via 10.0.2.1` inside the script. Note that pings won't work, but TCP and UDP should work. `slirp` package needs to be installed. Manual: http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/old/UserModeLinux-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: @phobic, If you need incoming connections, you need either to setup more proper tun/tap network or to activate Slirp's port forwarding (note that connections from localhost address like `127.0.0.1` may fail to work).

Comment: :. Thanks, network seems ok now, I also needed to mount procfs and allowed UML to use more memory, I will update in the evening if I get it to work.

Comment: @phobic, There are appropriate options in UML. Try `linux.uml --help`. You can mount procfs from inside the container like usual `mount -t proc proc /proc`. For performance, I expect about 50-fold slowdown for syscalls any maybe 2-fold slowdown for CPU-bound calculations.

Comment: I still cannot get it to work. I have trouble with python psutil, for which I needed to enable procfs. In UML python actually tells me that psutil does not exist, even though I installed it on the host. I tried to install it inside UML, but it is rather difficult (no access to sudoers, gcc complains about missing executable cc1, limits.h, and stddef.h). I started UML with root privileges to install psutil, linked /bin/cc to /bin/cc1, and tried to get the header files, but I am still not there yet.

Comment: Can you post a simple isolated example of Python failing to find something (that works on host, but fails in UML)? I can `strace` it on my side and try to fix. I don't think installation of some "psutil" (what is it?) should be done from inside UML (or that it would change anything).

Comment: Just now solved the issue; I installed python-psutil using apt-get instead of python pip (a python package manager). Probably using pip did not work due to the virtual environment in travis.ci. The next problem occurred, which is similar, but I hope I will get it to work eventually. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Now I've experimented and noticed that "gcc" fails to work (fails to find `ld`) in this setup and I don't know why. Trying to figure out.

Comment: Looks like setting corrent `PATH` (i.e. `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`) fixed `gcc`. Maybe it would fix other programs as well.

Comment: @phobic, So, has it worked? Are more adjustments needed?

Comment: So, I solved the Python related problems. But I cannot seem to use FUSE: https://travis-ci.org/joe42/CloudFusion/jobs/50845662

Comment: @phobic, It is telling you to load the module. Try loading it explicitly with `insmod`. See the example script in this answer; note the escaped backticks around `uname -r`. They are to load UML's module, not host kernel's one. You can also specify `init=/bin/bash` (not on Travis's side, on your localhost) and experiment inside UML more directly before deploying onto Travis.

Comment: I tried insmod, which didn't work: https://travis-ci.org/joe42/CloudFusion/jobs/50873977 On my PC it works fine though. I don't really know where the problem is, as it seems to work in your case.

Comment: I see this error: `overflow in relocation type 11 val e15d0fc0; 'fuse' likely not compiled with -mcmodel=kernel`. Have you changed anything in UML parameters or things have changed on Travis's side? I'll try re-testing my case. Update: restared my build: https://travis-ci.org/vi/execfuse/builds/48371659 , it worked. Maybe `mem=2G`?

Comment: @Vi. The error went away for me at `mem=256M` (first try of a different number). For future adventurers (needs a thorough cleanup, but proves the point): https://travis-ci.org/suffuse/go-suffuse/builds/69668142